# How to write PHP in XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have been trying for the longest time to write a simple php echo statement in a .xsl file, but every site that I look at does not seem to function for me when I enter a processing-instruction tag.  I even tried changing the namespace for php and I am not sure why my code is not outputting the echo statement. Here is my .xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="php" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <head>
            </head>
            <body bgcolor="#000">
                    <div class="main" style="background:lightblue;">
                        <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
                        echo 'OK IT DOESN't WORK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!';
                        </xsl:processing-instruction>
                        <xsl:for-each select="webpage/content/main">
                            <a href="{link}" style="color:#000; text-decoration:none;">
                                <h1><xsl:value-of select="heading" /></h1>
                                <h2><xsl:value-of select="subheading" /></h2>
                                <div class="img">
                                    <img src="../images/{image}" width="100%" height="auto"/>
                                </div>
                                <xsl:value-of select="description" />
                            </a>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also attempted to use the following tag to surround the html tags and then used the processing-instruction tag anywhere inbetween:

```
<xsl:result-document href="example.php" method="html">
</xsl:result-document>
```

AND Still No Luck.  Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *How* are you running this XSLT? `result-document` is an XSLT 2.0 (not 1.0) method. Check the source (PHP may be an HTML comment) as client browser shows here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVF6

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve: do you want to use XSLT to generate input to the PHP interpreter? How do you run your XSLT code, how do you look at or "execute" the result if you want PHP to be executed?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your `xsl:processing-instruction` doesn't work is simple.
You defined your output method as `html` with your

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html" />
```

instruction. **But HTML does not have *processing-instructions*!**
So simply change the `method` attribute of the `xsl:output` to "xml" and your code should work as expected.

**Summary:**
HTML does not have *processing-instructions*. Only XML does. With this change, some part of the output looks like

```
<?php 
                        echo 'OK IT DOESN't WORK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!';
                        ?>
```

which is (kind of) a valid *processing instruction*.
P.S.: I just tested it: `xhtml` also doesn't work as output method.

Comment: I changed to method attribute to equal xml and still no luck.  When I change the method attribute to php I displays without the processing instruction.  Why is this not functioning?

Comment: I succeeded with `<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" />`. BTW, there is no method attribute value named "php".

Comment: I copied the output line as you have it and it still is not outputting my processing-instruction.

Comment: The `xsl:output` line has to contain the `method="xml"` attribute. Otherwise it wouldn't be working.

Comment: Something is not working correctly.  because when I change the method to xml and the go to my index.xml file it outputs all my css code that I have in the head.

Comment: Sorry. I do not know what may cause this.

Comment: I think this is a misdiagnosis. Although HTML5 does not have processing instructions, the serialization rules for XSLT 1.0 were defined a long time ago, and they should produce output for a PI, though not in exactly the form PHP requires.

Comment: @MichaelKay: That's an interesting info. I tested both cases, and only the 'XML'  version did work as desired. The 'HTML'  version was missing the final `?>` part of the tag. I tested it both with `xsltproc` as well as a recent version of `saxon`.

Comment: On running this with Saxon 10 I found a bug. Saxon 9.9 produces the correct (though not useful) output.

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT and serialization specifications (all versions) say that this should produce the output `<?php echo 'OK IT DOESN't WORK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!';>` (plus some whitespace). This isn't actually useful; it was defined this way for historic reasons that are difficult to recall. HTML5 attaches no meaning to processing instructions, and they are serialized in a format that's not even useful for PHP.

I don't know why you aren't seeing this output, but the question is somewhat academic since the correct output wouldn't be useful to you anyway.

If I recall correctly, the XML output method isn't that useful for generating PHP scripts either, since PHP is not in the general case well-formed XML.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach:

Make the xslt using the xsl:param and feed those with php.

php:

```
<?php
$xmlUri      = '/some/path/to/your.xml';
$xslUri      = '/some/path/to/your.xsl';
$xmlDocument = new DOMDocument;
$xslDocument = new DOMDocument;

if ($xmlDocument->load($xmlUri) && $xslDocument->load($xslUri)) {

    $xsltProc = new XSLTProcessor();
    $xsltProc->setParam('pi', "OK IT DOESN't WORK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    if ($xsltProc->importStyleSheet($xslDocument)) {
        echo $xsltProc->transformToXML($xmlDocument);
    }
}
```

Your xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="pi"/>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html> 
      <head>
      </head>
      <body bgcolor="#000">
        <div class="main" style="background:lightblue;">
          <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
            <xsl:value-of select="$pi"/>
          </xsl:processing-instruction>
          <xsl:for-each select="webpage/content/main">
            <a href="{link}" style="color:#000; text-decoration:none;">
              <h1><xsl:value-of select="heading" /></h1>
              <h2><xsl:value-of select="subheading" /></h2>
              <div class="img">
                <img src="../images/{image}" width="100%" height="auto"/>
              </div>
              <xsl:value-of select="description" />
            </a>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```